# How to list all Flutter packages and version numbers

Tags: flutter

### This is two questions in one ...

I'm new to Flutter, and really liking it so far; this is a Flutter noob question.

In Flutter we specify the packages required in `pubspec.yaml`, and we install them using

```sh
flutter packages get
```

#### 1. how do I find out the available versions of a particular flutter package ?

For example, I'm using the `flutter_firebase_ui` but the version I'm using (`^0.0.13` which seems to be the latest based on my googling), conflicts with the `firebase_auth` version I'm using (`^0.14.0+5`).  I need to know which versions of each of  `flutter_firebase_ui` and `firebase_auth` are available so I can find compatable versions.

#### 2. where can I see a list of available Flutter packages ?

(and I don' feel that needs further explanation :)

Comment: check `pubspec.lock` to see the details of  version and dependency.

Comment: I am also looking for something like 'pip list' of Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) you can check all available versions of in package's Changelog or Versions.
for example, checkout all version of flutter_firebase_ui at here 
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_firebase_ui/versions.

To solve conflicts between packages you can look at this link for more info:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages

2) Here you can find all the available packages in flutter.

https://pub.dev/flutter

Answer (score 10):

This gives you a visual representation of all of the dependencies in your project

```
flutter pub deps
```